# dynamically constructing appengine model names in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a set of models Day1, ... ,Day7 .
How can I use an integer 1-7 to use the correct model?

```
class Day1 (db.Model):    #Monday
    courtday = db.ReferenceProperty(CourtDays)
    startTime = db.TimeProperty()
    endTime = db.TimeProperty()
    startTimeLunch = db.TimeProperty()
    endTimeLunch = db.TimeProperty()
    day = "Monday"

class Day2 (db.Model):    #Tuesday
    courtday = db.ReferenceProperty(CourtDays)
    startTime = db.TimeProperty()
    endTime = db.TimeProperty()
    startTimeLunch = db.TimeProperty()
    endTimeLunch = db.TimeProperty()
    day = "Tuesday"
```

Comment: You are really sure what you need all this separate tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one model for a day, since they are all the same..

```
class Day (db.Model):
    courtday = db.ReferenceProperty(CourtDays)
    startTime = db.TimeProperty()
    endTime = db.TimeProperty()
    startTimeLunch = db.TimeProperty()
    endTimeLunch = db.TimeProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()

days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
for dayname in days:
  newday = Day(name=dayname)
  newday.put()
```

Comment: I suppose you mean to then use `days = [Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday]`. But then how do you do the `monday = Day(name="Monday")` part for different days when you are know only the day number?

Comment: Will this work? `day = Day(name=days[day_num-1])` `day.put()`